# Parent receiver of child postMessage is always blank

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, postmessage

I have a parent webpage: [www.tablesandlegs.co.uk:8080](http://www.tablesandlegs.co.uk:8080) that opens a new window to a child webpage: [www.new.tablesandlegs:8085](http://www.new.tablesandlegs:8085). I can send message down to the child page quite easily however when i try to send back up, i can see my eventListener is invoked, but contents is empty:

Parent:

```
function loadNewSite() {
    var popup = window.open('www.new.tablesandlegs.co.uk:8080/tables');

    setInterval(() => {
        popup.postMessage('Testing 123', '*'); // I see this interval in the child window browser log
    }, 5000);
}

window.addEventListener('message', message_receive, false);

function message_receive(evt) {
    console.log('event', evt);  // <--- i see this from click in child
    console.log(evt);      // <--- this is empty
}
```

Child:

```
public parentWindow: any;

ngOnInit() {

window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {

    if(event.origin.includes('new') {
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log('from parent', event); // see logs from parent interval
        this.parentWindow = event;
    }
}

}

public clicked() {

    this.parentWindow.source.postMessage('you clicked something, this.parentWindow.origin);

}
```

When i click the `btn` on the html, i can see clicked() is invoked on the child popup & `console.log('event');` in parent is logged but the follow `console.log(evt)` is always blank;

Have tried sending from child to parent:

```
JSON.stringify()
{'test': 'msg'}
```

Both no luck

Note, many tutorials advise an iFrame may been needed? Is this absolutely necessary?

Comment: Don’t see why this should require iframes, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage mentions nothing like that, but explicitly states that it should work in a parent window / popup window context as well. Have you tried to use `window.opener` to acquire the reference to the popup’s parent, instead of going via the event source?

Comment: @CBroe yup i thought it should work without iFrames, especially parent > child postMessage works fine. Have tried window.opener, same result. Empty evt.

Answer (score 0):

1.In event child window post message to its parent,you forgot the quote on the message

2. In parent window:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (evt) => message_receive(evt), false);
```